# First query take more then 5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

so I have this query

```
SELECT a.`title`,a.`id`,a.`numvol`,a.`numepi`,a.`release_date`,
     (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `Release` r WHERE r.`article_id`=a.`id`) AS `num_rows`,
     (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `Article_views` av WHERE av.`article_id`=a.`id`) AS `num_rows2`
 FROM `Article` a  WHERE a.`type` = 'ani' ORDER BY a.`title` ASC
```

The first load takes up to 5 secs and if I do a refresh it will take about 0.001 sec, is there a way to uniform the loading time?

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             a   ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    567     Using where; Using filesort
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  av  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    5301    Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  r   ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    11717   Using where
```

I tried to do it with join but it didn't work at all so I gave up this way...

**Solution**

use barmar query. way better :) (and indexes -,-')

```
id  select_type     table          type     possible_keys   key         key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>     ALL      NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL    536     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY         a              eq_ref   PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4           r.art.. 1       Using where  
1   PRIMARY         <derived3>     ALL      NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL    574     Using where; Using join buffer
3   DERIVED         Article_views  index    NULL            article_id  4           NULL    5301    Using index
2   DERIVED         Release        index    NULL            article_id  4           NULL    11717   Using index
```

Thanks guys for your time and the solution :) I guess I need to redo a good part of this old project ahah :)

Comment: Warm???? should it really take that much time for such small table?

Comment: Are your tables of MyISAM or Innodb type? I am asking because it matters a lot

Comment: Cache? `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT a.`title`,a.`id`,a.`numvol`,a.`numepi`,a.`release_date`, `num_rows`, `num_rows2`
FROM `Article` a
JOIN (SELECT article_id, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
      FROM Release
      GROUP BY article_id) r
ON r.article_id = a.id
JOIN (SELECT article_id, COUNT(*) AS num_rows2
      FROM Article_views
      GROUP BY article_id) av
ON av.article_id = a.id
WHERE a.`type` = 'ani'
ORDER BY a.`title` ASC
```

In my experience, JOINs are faster than correlated subqueries.

For performance, make sure you have indexes on `Release.article_id` and `Article_views.article_id`.

Comment: wow this one worked great thank you :) (0.0914 sec) but what are index?? I added those index and it performs the same way :/ well it's still way better :)

Comment: You're building an application using a database and you don't know what indexes are? I think you need to go study how databases work, I'm not going to try to teach this here.

Comment: I guess I've rushed my learning a bit ahah thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess, 2nd try is benefit from `SQL QUERY CACHE`. I wonder if adding `SQL_NO_CACHE`, every try took 5 secs?

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE a.`title`,a.`id`,a.`numvol`,a.`numepi`,a.`release_date`,
....
```

**INDEXES**

Oops. you have no relevant INDEX. could you add following indexes?

```
ALTER TABLE Article ADD INDEX(type);
ALTER TABLE Release ADD INDEX(article_id);
ALTER TABLE Article_views ADD INDEX(article_id);
```

**More Efficient Query**

And your Query converted into `JOIN`. I guess this is much faster than yours. Assuming every `Article` has `Release` and `Article_views`

```
SELECT a.`title`,a.`id`,a.`numvol`,a.`numepi`,a.`release_date`,
     COUNT(r.id) AS `num_rows`,
     COUNT(av.id) AS `num_rows2`
FROM `Article` a JOIN Release r ON r.`article_id`=a.`id`
  JOIN Article_views av ON av.`article_id`=a.`id`
WHERE a.`type` = 'ani'
GROUP BY a.title, a.id, a.numvol, a.numepi, a.release_date
ORDER BY a.`title` ASC;
```

Comment: yep you are right, adding sql_no_cache to the query and it takes 5 secs each time... on the other hand, your query isn't working at all.. it took 61.7727 secs and didn't return the correct count for num_rows and num_rows2

Comment: @cloud1250000 Sorry, probably I made some mistakes. wait a minute plz. I'll try to fix.

Comment: Well I've just seen that I need to add relevant index.. but what does it do??

Comment: @cloud1250000 Could you test my query after adding indexes? indexes make query faster. and Barmar has suggested another query which looks better than mine.

Comment: I see, btw, without adding the index it took 4.6sec this time. I'd really like to understand what are the index.. is it really sure it's type the best choice for Article?

Comment: @cloud1250000 Wow, Barmar made best query. *"I'd really like to understand what are the index.. "* It's broad question, why don't you read this slides? http://www.slideshare.net/osscube/indexing-the-mysql-index-key-to-performance-tuning

Comment: so if I add a  AND a.`title` REGEXP '^([[:punct:]]|[\+?{}]|[0-9])' or  AND a.`title` LIKE '".$query."%' I should put an index on title too? but wouldn't it be better to only have one index?

Comment: @cloud1250000 Only `a.title LIKE "$query%"` can use index. refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html . And probably `FULLTEXT SEARCH` might help you if you want search title which has '%query%' http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

That significant improvement on query latency is due to internal MySQL cache functioning.

After the first execution of the query the result set is cached in RAM, so the results second query which just matches the previous, are immediately taken from the RAM without HDD accesses.

There are different points of view about MySQL internal cache, and experts often recommend to disable it in highload production environments using memecached, Redis or some other caching layer instead.

But definitely you should try to optimize performance of your query with caching turned off - 5 seconds is extremely slow.

1. Try not to use subqueries, cause MySQL optimizer is not performant on them.
2. Store values of the counters (results of `count()`) in separate table and update them properly. Then you can use just the counters values in your query without performing heavy database request each time.
3. Create indexes, for example, for `type` field.
4. Use `EXPLAIN` for further optimizations